# Python Django framework: deciding a model field's default value by primary key

Tags: python, django, django-models

In Django, is there a way to decide what kind of value I want to use for my model's field's default value, relatively to this model instance's primary key?
ex:
if I have a `Question` object that has a field `question_title` what I'm trying to do is to set up this field as:

```
question_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="title")
```

but instead of just say `default="title"`, I would like to say:

```
default="title"+self.pk
```

The problem is, (at least I think what the problem is) that when the class member been defined at runtime, there is no instantiation, so from Python interpretor level, there is no way to know what value of self.pk has.

if yes, I tried to implement the **init**() function, but still get a type error:

```
class Question(models.Model):

    question_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="untitled")
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200, default ="content")

    def __init__(self):
        self.question_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="title"+str(self.pk))
        self.question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200, default ="content")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_title
```

the error msg is:

```
__init__() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)
```

Comment: post full traceback

Comment: why not use a model manager instead of overriding `__init__` . Overriding init is not recommended

Comment: @ArpitSolanki thanks for mentioning that, it seems like this documentation is useful as you said https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/

Comment: Please update the `__init__` method to match the super method signature `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):`. You also might want to consider `pre_save`  signal.

Comment: Use a post_save signal

Answer (score 0):

Create a method callable in the default.

For example:

```
def get_default_title(instance, text):
    # this goes outside of your model
    title = "%s %s" % (text, instance.id)
    return title


question_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=get_default_title)
```

Let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: it doesn't work - `get_default_title` do not get both parameters